# GameObject.Find() in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, find, gameobject, object-pooling

This is a C# method I found in a Unity3D tutorial:

```cs
Public List<Piece> pieces = new List<piece>(); // list of pieces in the pool

public Piece GetPiece(PieceType pt, int visualIndex) {
    Piece p = pieces.Find(x => x.type == pt && x.visualIndex == visualIndex);
}
```

What I don't understand is in this line : `x => x.type == pt...`

Where does the "x" come from and why x.type?

Comment: Could you give us the tutorial link, please?

Comment: This is the link : https://youtu.be/LnXbsZfeyW8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is [`List<T>.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find) and has nothing to do with [`GameObject.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)!**

---

[`List<T>.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find):

> Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the first occurrence within the entire `List<T>`.
>
> The `Predicate<T>` is a delegate [(or in your case lambda expression)] to a method that returns `true` if the object passed to it matches the conditions defined in the delegate. The elements of the current `List<T>` are individually passed to the `Predicate<T>` delegate, moving forward in the `List<T>`, starting with the first element and ending with the last element. Processing is stopped when a match is found.

---

Then what you have there is a [Lambda Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) where `x` is the iterator variable like in

```
foreach(var x in pieces)
```

that is where the `x` comes from. It can basically called whatever you like. And its type is `Piece` so it depends on your `Piece` implementation what `x.type` is .. looking on your parameters I'ld say it is an `enum` called `PieceType`.

---

So it does basically the same as and is just a shorthand for

```
public Piece GetPiece(PieceType pt, int visualIndex) 
{
    foreach(var x in pieces)
    {
        if(x.type == pt && x.visualIndex == visualIndex) return x;
    }

    return default;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the `Find` definition, `public T Find (Predicate<T> match)`, you will see that it receives the `Predicate<T>` which is nothing than a function with parametar `T` and return value `bool`, `Func<T, bool>`. This effectively means that the sequence of the elements will be filtered based on the provided function.

One possible way to specify the `Func<T, bool>` is using C# language construct called lambda expression. That being said `x => x.type == pt...` is an lambda expression which defines the conditions of the element to search for.

Looking at the:

```
Piece p = Pieces.Find(x => x.type == pt && x.visualIndex == visualIndex)
```

The intention is to filter `Pieces` based on `type` and `visualIndex` where `x` is `Piece`. Don't be confused with `x`, you could use any literal. You could read it like:
*Give me each Piece x where x.type is pt and x.visualIndex is visualIndex*

Answer (score 2):

`x` is the `Piece` object that was found in the `Pieces` list and `x.type`is something that was a field defined inside the Piece class which in turn lets you have a `p` object with the same `PieceType` as `pt`

Answer (score 2):

In the `find` method you are declaring a lambda function (a [predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.8) to be more precise) and `x` is the variable of this function. According to this instruction, `x` is an instance of the `Piece` class and it has the attributes `type` and `visualIndex`.

This line means: "Find the first element on the `pieces` list where `type` is set to `pt` and `visualIndex` is set to `visualIndex`".

Answer (score 2):

```
Pieces.Find(x => x.type == pt && x.visualIndex == visualIndex)
```

Could be written as

```
Pieces.Find(singlePiece => singlePiece.type == pt && singlePiece.visualIndex == visualIndex)
```

Which translates to:

"Within collection "Pieces" find first element that it of type pt and whose visualIndex property is equal to visualIndex)"

"singlePiece" or "x" denotes what conditions must be met for element to be "found" using Find method.

Comment: Except `Find` only finds the **first** element that matches the condition. For finding all elements you would use Linq `IEnumerable.Where` or `List<T>.FindAll`